# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "8:30 AM"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to Parse "8:30 AM" but I am getting Unparseable Date Exception.

From my UI side I  am getting "8:30 AM" and "6:30 PM" kind of values but I have to convert that String into Date format and save that date in my database.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleDateFormat timingFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h a",
            Locale.US);
        String dateInString = "8:30 AM";

        try {
            // This line throws Unparseable exception
            Date date = timingFormat.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println(date);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 8 AM is in no way a date, it's an hour. How are you supposed to know/guess which date corresponds to it? Every day has an "8 AM"

Comment: And do you really think that `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` will be able to parse that? You should read the Javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> the year value of the parsed Date is 1970 with GregorianCalendar if no
>   year value is given from the parsing operation. The TimeZone value may
>   be overwritten, depending on the given pattern and the time zone value
>   in text.

try this

```
         SimpleDateFormat timingFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h a", Locale.US);
         Date date = timingFormat.parse("8 AM");
         System.out.println(date.toString());
```

Output

```
Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 IST 1970
```

**UPDATE**

To get today date,you can try something like this after parsing

```
     int hours = date.getHours();
     Date today = new Date();
     today.setHours(hours);
     System.out.println(today);
```

**Note** `getHours()` and `setHours` are deprecated methods.Its recommended to go for `Calendar`.You will have to set hours, minutes explicitly.

**UPDATE**

if input is 8:30 or so,then you will have to parse it like this

```
         SimpleDateFormat timingFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.US);
         Date date = timingFormat.parse("8:30 AM");
         System.out.println(date.toString());
```

Output

```
Thu Jan 01 08:30:00 IST 1970
```

Depending on the input,you need to select which kind of `format` you are insterested.You can check that whether string contains `:` or not,based on that you can use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Prince but can't we get current date after parsing

Comment: yes you can do.Retrieve hours from this date and take a new Date() and setHours in that.

Comment: Because when we try new Date() we get Wed Nov 18 15:15:01 IST 2015 value. I want this format with the time I am parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Prince but after set hours method println method gives Wed Nov 18 08:21:18 IST 2015 value. It changes the 8:00 value to 08:21:18 .

Comment: Prince thanks for your help I have set minute and second explicitly.

Comment: Hi Prince Let say If I am getting 8:30 AM type of string in place of 8 AM then by your parse method it is throwing exception. Is any other way to parse 8:30 AM. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to Parse 8:30 AM just change the formatter above with

SimpleDateFormat timingFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct but outdated.

As mentioned, the Question has an input string which means only a time-of-day while the java.util.Date class represents both a date *plus* a time-of-day.

What you need is a class that represents only a time-of-day. No such class in the older versions of Java before Java 8.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalTime`

The java.time classes include the [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class. This class represents a time-of-day without any date nor time zone.

Note that for the [formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) we [specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) using the English language to correctly identify the strings `AM` and `PM` which could vary by human language.

```
String input = "8:30 AM";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "h:m a" , Locale.ENGLISH );
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse ( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "localTime: " + localTime );
```

> localTime: 08:30

## Database

Next, the database. Eventually we should see [JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) updated to directly handle the java.time types. Until then, we must convert from java.time types to the old [`java.sql` types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html).

### Convert From `java.time` to `java.sql`

For this Question, that means the [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) class. That old `java.sql.Time` class has a new method for convenient conversions, [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalTime-).

```
java.sql.Time sqlTime = java.sql.Time.valueOf ( localTime );
```

From there, the JDBC driver converts from the java.sql time to the database type. For this Question, that probably means the standard [`TIME` SQL type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types).

### Pass java.sql.* Object To Database Via JDBC Driver

Use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to insert or update your data by passing that `sqlTime` variable seen above. Search StackOverflow.com for countless examples of such insert/update work in SQL.